# Возможно ли вообще cделать переход из фрагмента в фрагмент?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Например, при нажатии кнопки в `фрагменте1` пользователя перекинет в `франмент2`.

Если можно, то как?

Comment: можно, как только ввели фрагменты. Но делается это через *FragmentManager* который в любом фрагменте берётся из *Activity*

Comment: аххааха спасибо, а можете код примерный скинуть? Уже несколько недель ищу в интернете как лох ничего не нашел((((

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17699504/5292979

Comment: ооооо спасибо))) можно вопрос закривать)

Comment: @Андрей Дело в том, что вопросы здесь не столько для того, чтобы помочь именно вам, сколько облегчить решение аналогичной проблемы другим.